# GetProps returns less length for PR_ENTRYID

Tags: mapi

Trying to retrieve the PR_ENTRYID of a contact using GetProps function from a PST. It's returns 24 length, but when I checked in Outlooksky for same property it shows length as 70.  Any idea why GetProp is returning less length?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, multiple entry ids can refer to the same object (e.g. long term vs short term entry ids).

24 bytes sounds like a PST entry id for a message or a folder. Where in OutlookSpy do you see `PR_ENTRYID` of 70 bytes?

Comment: 24 byes for a Contacts( not for folder).                                                                                    This is what OutlookSpy shows : 00000000874E3A656E2B6646A579F961EDB70E9E07003BDC73C083F9614DAF8B2DC40962829800000000010E00003BDC73C083F9614DAF8B2DC40962829800003300974D0000                                  GetProp returns : 00000000F8B171053FE26A4FAA7F94557A75181F24002000

Comment: So where does 70 bytes come from and why is it important?

Answer (score 0):

70 bytes: if you import `pst` (`import/export option in outlook`) into the same folder that your,i.e., personal email

24 bytes: if you open `pst` as `open outlook data file`  instead of `import/export`.